# I'm trying to create a makefile

Tags: makefile

makefile:

```
lambda : main.o
    gcc -o lambda main.o
main.o : main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o

.PHONY : clean
```

all I get as an answer instead of my executable is

```
main.o: In function `fn':
main.c:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `pow'
main.c:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `pow'
main.c:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `log10'
main.o: In function `fnPrime':
main.c:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `pow'
main.c:(.text+0x246): undefined reference to `pow'
main.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `log10'
main.c:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lambda] Error 1
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Your Makefile is fine (sort of); the problem is in your C code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a reference to the Math library. You need to add **-lm** to the end of your make command

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a search in stackoverflow I find that the problem was that I didn't put the option -lm at the end of the linking line.

```
lambda : main.o
    gcc -o lambda main.o -lm
main.o : main.c
    gcc -c main.c -o main.o

.PHONY : clean
    clean : rm lambda main.o
```